# How do I upload a sitemap.xml file to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, xml-sitemap

I am using Node.js. My app is already in production. I created a sitemap.xml in my local directory but it currently identified as Untracked.

There are other answers that pertain to Ruby but I am unfamiliar with the language.

How do I push my file to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using ExpressJs, you need to create a route for sitemap and robots.txt

```
app.get("/sitemap.xml", (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + "/sitemap.xml"));
```

You can use the same procedure for your robots.txt files!

You can now push to Heroku and it will be tracked successfully!

Comment: From looking at website analytics bots and web scrapers target the path `/robots.txt` to try and manipulate your site. I highly do not recommend adding the path `/robots.txt` to your site.